# Métodos referenciados en Java8

Tags: java

echando un vistazo a un source me crucé con el siguiente código:

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> EXAMPLE_ITEM = ITEMS.register("example_item", ItemBase::new);
```

No comprendo muy bien qué devuelve `ItemBase::new`, o un supuesto `ItemBase::function`.

Entendedme que si he escrito la consulta es porque he leido el uso en distintas webs pero no acabo de comprender cómo usarlo y cuándo es útil.

Gracias! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `ItemBase::new` te crea una nueva instancia u objeto de un *ItemBase*. El operador **double colon ::** u **operador de referencia de metodo** es algo que se introdujo con java 8 para hacer que el código sea mas simple y legible. Lo que hace es abreviar una expresión lambda para llamar a cualquier método.

En el caso en el que preguntas hacer esto `ItemBase::new` es equivalente a esto

`() -> ItemBase()`

Te dejo este [enlace](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator) para que puedas ampliar mi respuesta. Disculpa que esté en ingles, no he leido de esto en español como para pasarte otra explicación.

Comment: No hay problema con el idioma, muchas gracias por la explicación :)